# XPath - return the count of the number of nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Given an xpath to a certain point in my xml lets say class - the node can have multiple children

essentially it will always have one tag called test and then multiple results (1 t or more)

```
<class>
    <test>
        //lots of other nodes in here
    </test>
    <result>
        //lots of other nodes in here
    </result>
    <result>
        //lots of other nodes in here
    </result>
    ...
    ...
</class>
```

How can I count the number of results sections there are? I would assume looping over every node and incrementing a variable everytime i find the text result would be quite inefficient for large files.

thanks

Comment: you can use `count` function

Comment: What did you try? Show us some effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as this

```
count(/class/result)
```